# Unable to start Neo4j Server(neo4j-community-2.2.3)

Tags: neo4j

After Remote System forced shutdown. Unable to start Neo4j Server. (neo4j-community-2.2.3)

data/log/console.log now says

```
2015-10-30 06:42:21.689+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000
2015-10-30 06:42:22.188+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

Updated Link to [messages.log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Vkj8GChs)

On searching the internet, possible solutions were

- Changing the startup time
- and the permission related issue

which I don't think is the solution since the server was running fine before.

How to start the server now?

Comment: Have you tried a `bin/neo4j start-no-wait` ?

Comment: Any errors in other log files?

Comment: @logisima Yes. Didnt Work.

Comment: @AlessandroNegro Here is the link to messages.log http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Vkj8GChs. "GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 344ms." Error from some days back.

Comment: That message is only a warning. Any message in neo4j.0.0.log? Are you sure there si no lock?

Comment: @AlessandroNegro No logs are getting appended to this file on started the server. This is what I can see there from September 2015

``INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Sep 30, 2015 7:38:54 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'``



Which lock? Nothing I did explicitly.

Comment: Have you tried augmenting the time waiting?

Comment: Your last entry into messages.log is dated at "2015-10-29 15:30:56.881", and what your console extract is dated from "2015-10-30 06:42:21".
Can we have sync logs  ?

Comment: @AlessandroNegro Do you mean changing the startup time? Yes, I did that.

Comment: @logisima Nothing is getting appended to messages.log.
Console.log says

``2015-10-30 13:26:47.565+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000
2015-10-30 13:26:48.054+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.``

Comment: Have you tried to migrate to 2.2.6?

Comment: @AlessandroNegro No, I haven't. Do I need to?

Comment: Make a copy of your database and try

Comment: @AlessandroNegro Should I instead migrate to 2.3 which is a significant release for Neo4j?

Comment: Yes if want you can jump to 2.3. Did you try with 2.2.6?

Comment: Tried upgrading to 2.3, didn't work. Though reinstalling 2.2.3 solves the issues.

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: Yes @AlessandroNegro. Thanks. :)